# "Немного" или "не много"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Написал такую фразу:

> *Я, правда, сам немного взял (смородинового листа), пожалел весь куст обрывать.*

И вот сомневаюсь, можно ли употребить *слитное **немного*** в том смысле, что я имел в виду. *Довольно мало,* аналогичное английскому *few* (если считать листья отдельно, а не собирательно), а не *взял чуть-чуть, но достаточно,* аналогичное *a few*. Понятно, что можно написать раздельно: *не много ≈ мало.* Но меня интересует, допустимо ли слитное написание *в близком смысле: маловато, **не**достаточно.*

Замечу ещё для полного понимания, что в варианте, аналогичном *a few*, который выражает не мою мысль, ударение на *взял,* а в варианте, аналогичном *few* и соответствующем тому как раз, что я и хочу выразить, ударение на *немн**о**го.*

Answer (score 2):

*Я, правда, сам // **не мнОго** взял (смородинового листа), пожалел весь куст обрывать.*

При отрицании ударение падает на наречие с частицей НЕ, которое обозначает **среднее количество**, то есть не стал много брать. (Обратим внимание **на паузу** перед  НЕ, она связана с актуальным членением предложения.)

Парный вариант: *Можно у вас взять **немного лИстьев** с куста?* Речь идет **о небольшом количестве**, позиция наречия безударная.

**О правилах**

При решении орфограммы учитывается **семантика слова и структура предложения.**

**1) Семантика**

Форма написания  наречий ***много*** и ***мало*** сама по себе может выражать семантику, так как эти наречия образуют **ряд с градацией признака,** который выглядит примерно так:
много — немало (почти много) —  не много и не мало (среднее количество) —  немного, почти мало — мало.

**2) Структура предложения**

Структура конкретного предложения может допускать  различные варианты: только утвердительный, только отрицательный, оба варианта, поэтому практически надо учитывать следующее.

При слитном написании НЕ  позиция наречия **безударная**, а при раздельном написании на слово с частицей НЕ падает **логическое ударение.**

Возможность слитного написания можно проверить **подстановкой синонима без НЕ.** Иногда оба варианта подходят, иногда один.

**Примеры**

Только слитно: *Я не горюю, просто лето на исходе, **немного жАль** того, что больше не вернешь* (логическое отрицание невозможно).

Логическое отрицание  часто встречается в начале предложения (речь идет о достаточном/среднем количестве): ***Не мнОго*** городов имеют такой великолепный театр.  **Не  мАло** дев вилось близ сердца твоего.

Comment: *При слитном написании НЕ позиция наречия безударная.* Тогда получается, что "немного" здесь может означать только "чуть-чуть, но хватает" и не может то, что я хотел, — "маловато"?

Comment: Если кто-то просит у вас листиков, то он скажет "немного", несколько штучек, небольшую горстку.  Это по ряду будет означать "небольшое количество". Если вы рвете листья со своего куста, то вы сорвете столько, сколько нужно, но при этом много рвать не будете. Это выражает отрицательная форма "не много".

Comment: Кроме того, структура вашего предложения уже выбрана под отрицательную форму. При таком построении  "немного, чуть-чуть" туда не впишется. Это вообще не ваша ситуация.

Comment: Я-то как раз не сорвал столько, сколько хотел, пожалел их. На мой вопрос behemothus-у Вы ответите однозначным "нет", правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Я поняла, что вы пожалели куст. Вы бы и много сорвали,  но не стали этого делать. Это можно выразить так: "не много сорвал, не стал много рвать." Ситуацию, а также ваше объяснение её можно обозначить только отрицательной формой.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо! Уже поставил пробел там. :)

Comment: Проверяйте ударением, очень удобно. Вот вам еще примерчик. Он пробежАл немного (чуть-чуть), потом остановился. - Он пробежал не мнОго (не очень большое расстояние), потом остановился.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно удобно. Но я и сам понимал значимость ударения и то, что раздельное написание в любом случае выражает мою мысль. Только хотел понять, слитное может выражать то же или ошибочно.

Comment: Одну и ту же ситуацию можно объяснить по-разному:  Стали рвать листья смородины, я тоже немного сорвАл. - Правда, я сорвал не мнОго, пожалел куст. Иногда бывает сложно разобраться, но ударение будет вашим верным помощником.

Comment: Остаётся сделать вывод, что тут с английским параллельная ситуация: там появляется артикль -> тут исчезает пробел и ударение перемещается на другое слово (обычно глагол).

Answer (score 1):

Я ничего не поняла из рассказа Ивана Свешникова (кроме того, что он - новый участник и обращаться с ним следует бережно).

> Что касается слитно-раздельно — однозначно слитно.

Так вот, что касается слитно-раздельно — однозначно раздельно.

Справка Грамоты.ру неоднократно, с одной и той же аргументацией, объясняет: ***при подчеркивании отрицания возможно раздельное написание*** (см. [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=300908) и [тут](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20288345)), а это именно наш случай, с пояснением - кустик пожалел.

Но и небезынтересно, как она сама пользуется словом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хоть здесь Грамота сама себе не противоречит, а то многие её совсем заклеймили (видимо, во многом справедливо). :)

Comment: Аэр, приходите сюда - https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/453078/%d0%92%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f/453090#453090 - это по Вашу душу.

Answer (score 0):

Что касается слитно-раздельно — однозначно слитно. Не аргументирую правилами железно, однако 1) без противопоставления *не много, [а мало]* теряется смысл раздельного написания, 2) *немного* и *не много* в таком контексте звучат абсолютно одинаково.

А вот смысл — полностью зависит от контекста и построения фразы. Ваш пример:

> Я, правда, сам немного взял (смородинового листа), пожалел весь куст обрывать

взял меньше, чем мог бы

И еще:

> Я, правда, сам немного взял, а другие - нет

взял некоторое количество, небольшое

> Нет, не одолжу, у самого денег немного

маловато, недостаточно.

Comment: Ну в принципе-то да, можно понять вашу логику... Но это все настолько субъективно. Сомнительно, что автор будет рассуждать так же.  А здесь хотят видеть ответы как-то обоснованные...

Answer (score -1):

> Но меня интересует, допустимо ли слитное написание в близком смысле:
> маловато, недостаточно.

Да писать-то можно, вопрос в том, поймут ли... Строго говоря тут действительно смысловая лакуна, не то чтобы неоднозначность, но какие-то акценты.

Вот Кузнецов вопреки своему обыкновению достаточно четко ловит этот момент, разделяя два значения (будем говорить "некоторое количество" и "незначительное количество").

> НЕМНОГО.  I. нареч. 1. Некоторое, незначительное время, недолго. Н.
> почитать перед сном. Мы н. поговорили и разошлись. Я отдохну н. 2.
> Некоторое, незначительное расстояние. До озера идти осталось н. Мы
> пройдём по лесу н. и выйдем на опушку. Далеко ли ехать? - Да нет, н.
> 3. В некоторой степени; чуть-чуть, слегка. Н. хромать, заикаться. Н. загореть,
> рассердиться, устать. Суп надо н. посолить. Юбку надо н.
> укоротить.
>
> II. числ. колич. В небольшом количестве; мало. Выпить н.
> воды. Собрать н. грибов. Друзей у него н. У нас есть н. времени.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE&all=x

Но тут такое дело... Вне контекста, прямо указывающего на иное, второе значение более правдоподобно - хотя бы потому что количественное числительное куда более естественно при материальных объектах, наречие "немного" требует  явного глагола без дополнения, да и то не всякого.

Так что я все-таки бы остерегся с пониманием "немного" в любом ином смысле.
**"Немного"** - это в небольшом количестве. И только оно, если явно не указано иное.

Я написал несколько витиевато, ибо не совсем понял, какое именно значение для вас сомнительно. Аналогия с английским, признаюсь, меня еще более запутала.

Comment: Да, я не всё хорошо понял, к сожалению. Но коротко: если оставить слитное написание, оно может означать "недостаточно" с ударением на само наречие?

Comment: *Но коротко: если оставить слитное написание, оно может означать "недостаточно"* - Расшифруйте. Я потому ни разу не написал "**ваше** понимание", что здесь какое-то недопонимание самой постановки. немного - это мало. Почему недостаточно-то?! Кому-то и "много" -  недостаточно.

Comment: *с ударением на само наречие?*  - наречие оно само по себе ударяемая часть речи. О чем вы?

Comment: Я так вижу, что можно сказать с ударением на "взял" в значении *я взял немножко, но этого вполне достаточно.* Как по-английски с артиклем: a few, a little — сколько-то есть и хорошо, нет проблемы нехватки. То есть сказать можно в таком смысле, ***но в данном случае я имел в виду как раз другое*** (что маловато будет).

Comment: *Друзей у него н.* Это, кстати, сомнительный пример, и, судя по большинству высказанных мнений, здесь подчёркнутое отрицание и должно писаться раздельно.

Comment: *Это, кстати, сомнительный пример...  подчёркнутое отрицание и должно писаться раздельно* - меня всегда забавляло, как это большинством голосов решается, не что сказал автор, а что он должен сказать. Нет, здесь нет подчеркнутого отрицания и раздельное написание было бы авторской вольностью. Допустимо, но именно как авторское понимание.

Comment: *Я так вижу, что можно сказать с ударением на "взял" в значении* - мой бедный мозг отказывается понимать смысл вашего видения. Простите. ((( У Кузнецова примеры на два значения слова "немного". Вы, как я начинаю догадываться, выводите какое-то третье?! Я его не понимаю.

Comment: Ну не знаю... В смысле "какое-то количество" я бы перестроил фразу: *У него есть немного (сколько-то) друзей* с ударением на "друзей". А когда "немного" в конце, поневоле на него падает смысловое ударение и получается смысл "мало". Допускаю, что автор мог не иметь в виду отрицания (пытаясь поверить вам), но осмыслить тогда его задумку не могу... @Sharon: что думаете по этому поводу?

Comment: Нет, я третьего не вывожу, а понимаю так же, как и Sharon (посмотрите наше обсуждение под её ответом): Кузнецов рассматривает две части речи, и в обоих случаях, на мой взгляд, ударение не должно падать на само слово, а значение "сколько-то" или "чуть-чуть", но без оттенка нехватки.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Так вы про смісловое ударение? Сейчас и раньше? Так его здесь нету вовсе. Произнесенная с естественной интонацией фраза может с одинаковім успехом означать "Друзей у него немного, а в товарищах весь посёлок", ""Друзей у него немного, а вот к жене друзья ходят, пока его дома нет", "Друзей у него немного: двоих или троих я знаю". Ну и еще сорок бочек арестантов. Ей-богу, вы ищите то, что никто не прятал.  Нет в этом словеве "немного" какого скрытого смысла.

Comment: *Нет, я третьего не вывожу, а понимаю так же* - Давайте лучше на Кузнецова ориентироваться. Sharon - это вообще вещь в себе для наших разговоров. )))

Comment: Не знаю, я бы во всех ваших примерах с друзьями раздельно написал.

Comment: *Не знаю, я бы во всех ваших примерах с друзьями раздельно написал.* Мне кажется, это тупик. Вы прыгаете с одного на другое, как я могу донести до вас свою простую мысль?! Но я все-таки сделаю последнюю попытку ответить на вашу реплику. Вы можете писать как угодно, но я не спрашивал, как бы вы написали. Я вам попытался объяснить, что в исходной фразе нет логического ударения, ибо оно может падать на любой их членов. Вот раздельном написании - да, акцент именно на отрицании. **НЕ (много)**.

Comment: *"У него есть немного (сколько-то) друзей" с ударением на "друзей".* Тут я перепутал: ударение не на "друзей", а на "есть", хотя, может, и на оба слова. *Я вам попытался объяснить, что в исходной фразе нет логического ударения, ибо оно может падать на любой их членов.* Я понял ваше мнение и жалею, что не могу с вами согласиться, — сам вижу по-другому. Жалею также, что кто-то поставил вам минус (минусовать это уж последнее дело), и очень надеюсь, что наше несогласие по этому вопросу не испортит отношений в целом.

Comment: Нету здесь никакого ударения. Оно может быть на любом члене. А при нормальном прочтении его нету вообще. Это тупик. DIXI