# Верно ли употреблено слово "ассоциация"?

Tags: точное-словоупотребление

Новичку на сайте:

> ...бонус за ассоциацию учётных записей не учитывается.
>
> ---

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

**АССОЦИАЦИЯ** [от лат. associare - присоединять]. **1.** Объединение лиц или учреждений одного рода деятельности; союз. *Краеведческая а. А. научных работников. Вступить в ассоциацию промышленных предприятий.* **2.** *Книжн.* Группа, сочетание, соединение чего-л.; сообщество. *А. растений. Звёздная а.* **3.** *Книжн.* Связь между отдельными психическими актами (представлениями, мыслями, чувствами), при которой один вызывает другой. *А. по сходству, по смежности. А. между звучанием и значением слова. Прошлое вызывает самые неожиданные ассоциации с настоящим. Запоминать английские имена по ассоциации с русскими* (по ассоциативной связи).

Comment: Может, имеется в виду просто "объединение"? Тогда, мне кажется, нельзя сказать "ассоциация".

Comment: Тёмыч, а к кому с этим постучаться? Если это брак, то местный, сайтовый.

Comment: А где это написано?

Comment: Это сайт обращается к новичку с пояснением, когда он сможет оставлять комментарии (кажется); высвечивается автоматически, но я уже не найду где.

Comment: Этот сайт? ****

Answer (score 1):

Если словом "Ассоциация" назван процесс присоединения (объединения) учетных записей — это неверно. Процесс можно назвать словом "Ассоциирование".

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/ассоциирование](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)